# Binding a WPF DataGrid to a List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I know this has been asked dozens of times before, but I can't figure out what (elementary) mistake I'm making here.

I have a program which presents a tabbed window. The number of tabs of a certain type is dynamically defined, so I created a UserControl (NTab) which inherits from Tab, that way I just need to append (or remove) another NTab to the TabControl and we're in business.

Now, each of these NTabs will have a DataGrid where the user inputs some X-Y coordinates. My thought was to create a NPoint class with X and Y properties and a List which I could bind to the DataGrid. To do so, I wrote the code below.

I understood that this would bind `Points`, which is an `ICollectionView` of my `List<NPoint>`, to the `DataGrid` at the end of the .xaml, however when I run the program I get an "empty" grid, as shown below. There is clearly a DataGrid there, but it isn't showing any data, evidently.

[image: Window with empty grid, not even showing rows or columns]

I compared my code with the code from [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html), with regards to the DataGrid in the .xaml, the code-behind and the definition of the data element (in my case NPoint, in the tutorial's case, Consumer), but haven't seen what's wrong in mine for it to not work while the tutorial does. Any ideas?

**NPoint**

```
public class NPoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    double _X;
    double _Y;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public double X 
    { 
        get { return _X; }
        set
        {
            _X = value;
            EmitPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }
    public double Y
    { 
        get { return _Y; }
        set
        {
            _Y = value;
            EmitPropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }
    void EmitPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    public NPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        _X = x;
        _Y = y;
    }
}
```

**NTab.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.NTab"
         x:Name="ThisTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="4"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Points, ElementName=ThisTab}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**NTab.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class NTab : UserControl
{
    List<NPoint> _Points;
    public ICollectionView Points {get; private set;}
    public NTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        SetupCoords();
        //nSections.ValueChanged += nSectionsChanged;
        _Points = new List<NPoint>(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            _Points.Add(new NPoint(i, i));
        Points = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_Points);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just from a quick look at your NPoint class: You should do `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));` (currently you use "Y" as event args). Although, this should only cause displaying wrong values for X, not causing an empty view...

Comment: The DataGrid appears to be empty because DataGrid does not know how to display NPoint objects, neither have you established any columns in the DataGrid as far as i can see...

Comment: Thanks for the `PropertyChanged` typo, silly mistake (corrected). But even that doesn't change anything. And I didn't define any columns in the DataGrid because `AutoGenerateColumns` is true by default. Therefore my understanding is that the DataGrid would look at the two public properties of `NPoint` and create two rows for it, just as in the tutorial I mentioned (http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

Comment: Yepp, you are right with AutoGenerateColumns. But are you certain that it still is `true` for your datagrid (perhaps you use a modified default style or something).

Comment: Wait... i know. Your binding... i post new answer (i deleted my old, incorrect answer).

Comment: I just tried putting AutoGenerateColumns="True" and it still doesn't work, unfortunately. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid does not show data, because the binding does not work. Let's take a look at your existing binding:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" />
```

The binding tries to access the points property of the DataContext of NTab. Whatever the NTab's DataContext, it does not seem to be your point list.

You should be able to fix the problem bei either setting the DataContext to the NTab instance with the *Points* property:

```
public NTab()
{
    ...
    Points = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_Points);
    DataContext = this;
}
```

or (preferably) you do a binding by element name in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.NTab" x:Name="thisNTab" ...>
    ...
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Points, ElementName=thisNTab}" />
</UserControl>
```

This alone will not yet give you the result, since the binding will not be aware if and when the *Points* property changes. Either implement the *INotifyPropertyChanged* mechanism, or turn *Points* into a DependencyProperty. Below the code for the using a read-only DependencyProperty:

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey PointsPropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        "Points",
        typeof(ICollectionView),
        typeof(NTab),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
    );
public static DependencyProperty PointsProperty = PointsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public ICollectionView Points
{
    get { return (ICollectionView) GetValue(PointsProperty ); }
    private set { SetValue(PointsPropertyKey, value); }

}
```

Comment: Neither of these did it, unfortunately. I have updated the OP with the corrections you've suggested, but the error still persists. :S

Comment: Yes, i forgot one thing. The Points property also need to fire an update event if it changes. I will update my answer using a DependencyProperty for that purpose (but you could also use INotifyPropertyChanged, if you like).

Comment: I'm updating my code now to check this out, but I'm finding it really odd. I've run the code of the tutorial I've mentioned in the OP and it works, and he doesn't use Dependencies at all. He has in fact almost zero code-behind.

Comment: @Wasabi, note that in the example you referred to the Customer list is initialized when the ViewModel is created. When the ViewModel is assigned to the DataContext, it triggers re-evaluation of any databinding using this DataContext -- and when this occurs, the customer list has already been populated. In your code, the Points list is populated after *InitializeComponent*, during which the databinding to the still empty *Points* property has been established. Without any change notification mechanism, the databinding would not be aware of any change to the *Points* property.